# What is jasper report complete library

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I want reporting from my *Java* application with *JasperReports*.

I downloaded `jasperreport-5.5.2.jar` library from [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library/releases) and add it.
but i think some classes not found!

I just wrote this code:

```
JasperDesign jd=JRXmlLoader.load("report1.jrxml");
```

and got below Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/digester/Digester
    at javaapplication71.JavaApplication71.main(JavaApplication71.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.digester.Digester
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
Java Result: 1
```

Can someone tell me what is a complete library for *JasperReports*?

Answer (score 0):

I ll assume that your are using maven :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-digester</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-digester</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this link you have a list of required jars: [Using Jasper](http://sameh-nassar.blogspot.com/2009/10/using-jasper-reports-with-jdeveloper.html). The last one, is not mandatory except when you are loading and compiling the report (i.e: the file with .jrxml report), instead of the pre-compiled one (i.e: the file with .jasper extension).

P.S: The list contains only the fundamental jars to make it work. Afterwards it depends on other features / extenstions you might use.